Unable to define the sites for an App Registration for SahrePoint with Site.Selected
I have this App registration inside Azure with Site.Selected for SharePoint online:-

I want to define the sites for the above "Sites.Selected", so I tried the following:-
$siteUrl = "https://*.sharepoint.com/sites/integration-prod"

$clientId = "2**0a"

$certThumbprint = "7**EA"

$tenant = "**.onmicrosoft.com"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant

$writeperm = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions "Write" -Site $siteUrl -AppId $clientId -DisplayName "SPGPIntegration-Test"

$PermissionId = Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppIdentity $clientId

Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site $siteurl -PermissionId $(($PermissionId).Id) -Permissions "FullControl"

But I got these errors:-

Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission: {"error":{"code":"AccessDenied","message":"Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.","innerError":{"date":"2024-09-17T14:01:55","request-id":"38072694-80cf-4235-9b4c-3d0335ee72ff","client-request-id":"38072694-80cf-4235-9b4c-3d0335ee72ff"}}}

Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission: Forbidden (403): Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.   

Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'PermissionId'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

any advice on this please?
Thanks
EDIT
I also tried with an App Registration which have full control but got the exact error , here what i tried, so i have 2 client IDs (one for the App registration with full control , while the other for the App registration which have Site.Selected), as mentioned in the description:-
$siteUrl = "https://*****"

$clientId = "Client ID For the App Registration which have full control"

$certThumbprint = "Thumbprint For the App Registration which have full control"

$tenant = "****.onmicrosoft.com"

connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant

$writeperm = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions "Write" -Site $siteUrl -AppId "Client ID For the App Registration which have Sites.Seleced" -DisplayName "SPGPIntegration-Test"

$PermissionId = Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppIdentity "Client ID For the App Registration which have Sites.Seleced""

Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site $siteurl -PermissionId $(($PermissionId).Id) -Permissions "FullControl"

but got the exact same error...

Microsoft Graph API: Sites.FullControl.All is required to resolve the error

@Rukmini on which App registration? the one which have FullControl on the sharepoint sites? or on the one which have selected.sites?

The app which has  FullControl on the sharepoint sites

Created a Microsoft Entra ID Application and granted same API permissions as you:

When tried the script got the same errors:

To resolve the error, you need to grant Microsoft Graph   Sites.FullControl.All application type API permission to the application

After granting the API permission I am able to do the operations successfully by modifying the script like below:
$siteUrl = "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/testrukk"

$appName = "SharePointPnPApp"

$clientId = "ClientID"

$certThumbprint = "XXX"

$tenant = "XXX.onmicrosoft.com"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -ClientId $clientId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant


if ($permission -ne 'FullControl' ) {
    Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppId $clientId -DisplayName $appName -Site $siteUrl -Permissions "Write"
}
else {
    Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppId $clientId -DisplayName $appName -Site $siteUrl -Permissions Write
    $PermissionId = Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -AppIdentity $appId
    Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site $siteUrl -PermissionId $(($PermissionId).Id) -Permissions FullControl
}

Get-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Site "https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/testrukk"


Reference:
Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission | PnP PowerShell

just to be clear, now i do not want the App registration which has selected.sites to have full control on Graph.. so i can grant this permission to the App registration i will be using to assign the selected.sites ? correct? i mean i have 2 app registrations one with full control (on SharePoint + Graph ) and the other only Selected.Sites on SharePoint? correct?

Yes you can do it

@Rukmini ok worked well now
